# Merge insert row wise on time coulmn , keep all the data frames of multiple data set

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am a novice in pandas and have followed many documents and threads but am not finding a solution. I have to merge three different data sets. The data sets have time stamps. I have to merge the data sets sothat the frames are in time order. Please help.

```
    df1=
    2017-09-28 19:00:48.035883   116.035883 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 FA 02 C2 FF FC CF FF C2
    2017-09-28 19:00:53.035358   121.035358 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 F9 02 F2 02 FF FF FF F9
    2017-09-28 19:00:53.035596   121.035596 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 FA 02 C2 FF FC CF FF C2
    2017-09-28 19:00:58.035314   126.035314 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 F9 02 F2 02 FF FF FF F9
    2017-09-28 19:00:58.035796   126.035796 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 FA 02 C2 FF FC CF FF C2
    2017-09-28 19:00:59.856818   127.856818 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 F9 02 F2 02 FF FF FF F9

    df2=
    2017-09-28 19:00:55.168703  [ RESPONSE ]   37 f4 67 13 4e d6 02 b2 59 c2 e6 82
    2017-09-28 19:00:55.182446  [  REQUEST ]   f4 37 27 14 00 00 00 20 51 ef e2 0d f1
    2017-09-28 19:00:55.213749  [ RESPONSE ]   37 f4 7f 27 78
    2017-09-28 19:00:55.274877  [ RESPONSE ]   37 f4 67 14
    2017-09-28 19:00:55.283833  [  REQUEST ]   f4 37 31 01 0f 1f 04

    df3=
    2017-09-28 19:00:55.069731 145077 107.6890 231   NM_ReadySleepState
    2017-09-28 19:00:55.069792 145078 107.6890 232   NM_ReadySleepState
    2017-09-28 19:00:55.120177 145079 107.7420 233   SW2 heartbeat
    2017-09-28 19:00:55.190568 145080 107.8080 234   SW1 heartbeat

merged=
2017-09-28 19:00:48.035883   116.035883 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 FA 02 C2 FF FC CF FF C2
2017-09-28 19:00:53.035358   121.035358 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 F9 02 F2 02 FF FF FF F9
2017-09-28 19:00:53.035596   121.035596 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 FA 02 C2 FF FC CF FF C2
2017-09-28 19:00:55.069731 145077 107.6890 231   NM_ReadySleepState
2017-09-28 19:00:55.069792 145078 107.6890 232   NM_ReadySleepState
2017-09-28 19:00:55.120177 145079 107.7420 233   SW2 heartbeat
2017-09-28 19:00:55.168703  [ RESPONSE ]   37 f4 67 13 4e d6 02 b2 59 c2 e6 82
2017-09-28 19:00:55.182446  [  REQUEST ]   f4 37 27 14 00 00 00 20 51 ef e2 0d f1
2017-09-28 19:00:55.190568 145080 107.8080 234   SW1 heartbeat
2017-09-28 19:00:55.213749  [ RESPONSE ]   37 f4 7f 27 78
2017-09-28 19:00:55.274877  [ RESPONSE ]   37 f4 67 14
2017-09-28 19:00:55.283833  [  REQUEST ]   f4 37 31 01 0f 1f 04
2017-09-28 19:00:58.035314   126.035314 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 F9 02 F2 02 FF FF FF F9
2017-09-28 19:00:58.035796   126.035796 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 FA 02 C2 FF FC CF FF C2
2017-09-28 19:00:59.856818   127.856818 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 F9 02 F2 02 FF FF FF F9
```

after suggestion from Jezrael:

```
#set_index("DateTime") for all
mixDfs=[df1,df2,df3]
mix= pd.concat(mixDfs)
print list(mix)
print mix.head(10)
['Data', 'DateTime_string']
                                                                     Data  \
```

DateTime

```
2017-09-28 19:00:48.035883    116.035883 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 FA 02...   
2017-09-28 19:00:53.035358    121.035358 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 F9 02...   
2017-09-28 19:00:53.035596    121.035596 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 FA 02...   
2017-09-28 19:00:58.035314    126.035314 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 F9 02...   
2017-09-28 19:00:58.035796    126.035796 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 FA 02...   
2017-09-28 19:00:59.856818    127.856818 2  5B7             Rx   d 8 F9 02...   
2017-09-28 19:00:55.069731           145077 107.6890 231   NM_ReadySleepState   
2017-09-28 19:00:55.069792           145078 107.6890 232   NM_ReadySleepState   
2017-09-28 19:00:55.120177                145079 107.7420 233   SW2 heartbeat   
2017-09-28 19:00:55.190568                145080 107.8080 234   SW1 heartbeat   

                                       DateTime_string  
DateTime                                                
2017-09-28 19:00:48.035883  2017-09-28 19:00:48.035883  
2017-09-28 19:00:53.035358  2017-09-28 19:00:53.035358  
2017-09-28 19:00:53.035596  2017-09-28 19:00:53.035596  
2017-09-28 19:00:58.035314  2017-09-28 19:00:58.035314  
2017-09-28 19:00:58.035796  2017-09-28 19:00:58.035796  
2017-09-28 19:00:59.856818  2017-09-28 19:00:59.856818  
2017-09-28 19:00:55.069731  2017-09-28 19:00:55.069731  
2017-09-28 19:00:55.069792  2017-09-28 19:00:55.069792  
2017-09-28 19:00:55.120177  2017-09-28 19:00:55.120177  
2017-09-28 19:00:55.190568  2017-09-28 19:00:55.190568
```

Comment: @ Julien : several methods including df1.merge(df2,on="DateTime").merge(df3,on="DateTime") apart from the concate proposed by Jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need create `DatetimeIndex` from first column and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) - also is necessary first column in each DataFrame contains datetimes only.

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfs = [pd.to_datetime(x.set_index(df.columns[0])) for x in dfs]

df = pd.concat(dfs).sort_index()
```

Comment: It did not work. Rather the dfs get concatenated one after another.

Comment: Without your data hard find error. But it seems your dataframes have no first column datetime only. Is possible check it?

Comment: all the data frames are processed by the same function and hence have exactly the same coulmns. The index is infact datetime.

Comment: Can you explain more your bad data output?

Comment: example: df3 frame at 19.0.55 time is not in the correct place and so is df2 frame in the concatenated output.

Comment: I think you forget `sort_index()`, mea culpa, I add it to my answer later :(